# htaccess Mod-rewrite - Getting querystring from file name and forward to php file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have created a nice php script. There is a list of user avatars in my database and avatar.php?id=xxx outputs that avatar as an image with the help of header("Content-Type: image/jpeg").

My avatar link is mywebsite.com/avatar.php?id=1. I want to use those avatars on different websites. However, in most of the websites PHP is not allowed and link must end with ".jpg".

So what I want to do is to create a ModRewrite rule.

I could turn JPG into PHP but then it will again not end with .jpg because of the querystring. So I thought putting the querystring in the file name can be a solution

Basically I want to forward

```
mywebsite.com/avatar**54**.jpg
mywebsite.com/avatar**17**.jpg
```

to

```
mywebsite.com/avatar.php?id=54
mywebsite.com/avatar.php?id=17
```

So my avatar links will end with .jpg but it will be calling a php script which gets the avatar with that ID from the database.

I also have this currently in my htacess file which lets me hide php extensions.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

So how can I achieve what I want to do without breaking or interfering my current rewrite rules? Or is that even possible?

Edit 1: I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^avatar([^/]*)\.jpg$  /avatar.php?id=$1  [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and sharing in case of someone else needs it

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^avatar([0-9]+)\.jpg$ avatar.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

this worked like a charm!